# SQLAlchemy how to group_by relation?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, aggregation

Here are the models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(CHAR, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(CHAR)
    last_name = Column(CHAR)
    email = Column(CHAR)
    receive_reports = Column(Boolean)


class MailPiece(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mail_pieces'

    id = Column(CHAR, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime)
    template_id = Column(CHAR, ForeignKey('templates.id'))


class Template(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'templates'

    id = Column(CHAR, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(CHAR)
    created_by_id = Column(CHAR, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = relationship(User, backref='templates')
```

I want to send to users reports with: which templates they are sent and how many mail pieces was sent for each template.

I wrote the code:

```
        stmt = self.session.query(MailPiece.template_id, func.count('*')
                               .label('mail_pieces_count')).filter(
            MailPiece.created_at > day_ago,
            MailPiece.created_at < now,
            ).group_by(MailPiece.template_id).subquery()

        query = self.session.query(Template, stmt.c.mail_pieces_count).\
            filter(Template.user.has(receive_reports=True)).\
            join(stmt, Template.id == stmt.c.template_id)
```

But this is slightly not what I wanted. I got result grouped by templates but need list grouped by users where each user will have templates. So in that way I can iterate through users list and send report to each user with summary.

Current result:

`[<Template(id='123', name='Test', mail_pieces_count='123', user=<User(id=1212, first_name='Some name', last_name='Some lastname')>)>, <Template(id='456', name='Test2', mail_pieces_count='456', user=<User(id=1212, first_name='Some name', last_name='Some lastname')>)>]`

Expected result:

`[<User(id=1212, first_name='Some name', last_name='Some lastname, templates=[<Template(id='123', name='Test', mail_pieces_count='123')>, <Template(id='456', name='Test2', mail_pieces_count='456')>,])>]`

In other words, now it can be represented like:
Current:

```
templates = [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "Test",
        "mail_pieces_count": 123,
        "user": {
            "id": 1212,
            "first_name": "Some name",
            "last_name": "Some lastname"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 456,
        "name": "Test2",
        "mail_pieces_count": 456,
        "user": {
            "id": 1212,
            "first_name": "Some name",
            "last_name": "Some lastname"
        }
    }
]
```

Expected:

```
users = [
    {
        "id": 1212,
        "first_name": "Some name",
        "last_name": "Some lastname",
        "templates": [
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "Test",
            "mail_pieces_count": 123
        },
        {
            "id": 456,
            "name": "Test2",
            "mail_pieces_count": 456
        },]
    },
]
```

Comment: can you add a few data records and expected result?

Comment: @Danila Ganchar question updated.

Comment: I think you might need something like [Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) if you want `mail_pieces_count` to appear as a property of `Template`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of current output:

You build a query using *Template class*:

```
self.session.query(Template, stmt.c.mail_pieces_count)
```

This is the main reason why you got `Template` instances instead of `User`. Below just an example how to get expected result.

> **Note!** I just try to explain how it works. My answer isn't related to optimization, performance etc.

```
# I skipped filters...
stmt = (session.query(MailPiece.template_id, func.count('*')
        .label('mail_pieces_count'))
        .group_by(MailPiece.template_id).subquery())
# to tie templates with upper subquery
stmt2 = (session.query(Template.created_by_id, stmt.c.mail_pieces_count)
         .join(stmt, Template.id == stmt.c.template_id)
         .subquery())
# User query - to tie template id with user id
query = session.query(User, stmt2.c.mail_pieces_count).join(
    stmt2,
    # you can add additional conditions into JOIN ON...
    and_(User.id == stmt2.c.created_by_id, User.receive_reports.is_(True))
)

for result in query:
    print("count: %s" % result.mail_pieces_count)
    print("user: %s" % result.User)
    print("templates: %s" % result.User.templates)
```

**JFYI.** If we look at console you will find that alchemy will do 1 query per iteration:

```
### one more select when you use result.User.templates
2019-02-11 13:02:24,702 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT templates.id AS templates_id, templates.name AS templates_name, templates.created_by_id AS templates_created_by_id 
FROM templates 
WHERE %(param_1)s = templates.created_by_id
```

You can add `Template` into query to avoid this, but in this case you will get the number of records equal to the number of **templates** (not **users**):

```
stmt2 = (session.query(Template, stmt.c.mail_pieces_count)
         .join(stmt, Template.id == stmt.c.template_id)
         .subquery())
# select User and Template 
query = session.query(User, Template, stmt2.c.mail_pieces_count).join(
    stmt2,
    and_(User.id == stmt2.c.created_by_id)
)

for result in query.all():
    print("user: %s" % result.User)
    print("template: %s" % result.Template)
```

So summarize, you need to use a *specific class* if you need to get *instances of the class* as a result:

```
session.query(ExpectedClass).other_methods()...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer. That's actually does not solve the problem described above (I wanted to get data in this way so that I can just iterate through list with `users` and be able to get templates which was sent in some time range and `mail_pieces_count` for each template) but I realized that this is not the smartest way to do what I want :D